# 2 struct using 1 pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am working on my linked list project in C, but I'm having some difficulty using 2 structs with only one pointer.

Example like this

```
struct makanan
{
    char nama [50];
    char nama_menu[50];
    float qty;
    int jumlah_bayar;
    int nomor;
    int harga;
    struct makanan *next;
    struct makanan *prev;
};
struct makanan *head;
struct makanan *bantu;
struct makanan *tail;

//menu's declaration
struct menu_makanan
{
    int harga;
    char nama_makanan[50];
};
```

Since my teacher said that must used at least 2 struct in this program, I want to ask:

- How can `*head`, `*bantu`, `*prev` and `*next` be used in `struct menu_makanan`?

Comment: Is that what your teacher meant when saying that? Just move them inside the list.

Comment: If `head`, `bantu`, and `tail` are supposed to identify the list of foods (makanan) on the menu, then those should be declared inside the `struct menu`. Every menu will have its own separate linked list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that a menu (`menu_makanan`) should contain a list of items (`makanan`) in some shape or form, and given that `makanan` contains the pointers to make a list, it seems logical that you should be using:

```
struct menu_makanan
{
    int harga;
    char nama_makanan[50];
    struct makanan *head;
};
```

The `harga` member could hold a count of the number of items in the list pointed at by `head`, or it could be some other value (since the length can be derived on demand if need so be).

If you wish, you could add a `struct makanan *tail;` member to `menu_makanan` too.

Now the global variables `head` and `tail` are redundant; that's usually a good thing.  Avoid global variables when you can.  Since I'm not sure what `bantu` does, I can't tell whether that's redundant too, but there's a moderate chance it is, or can be made, redundant too.